# C - memory leak (how to fix)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, char, free

I have to fix memory leaks from this function, but I have no idea how to do this:
I tried to create a const char in GetWord and return him, but strcpy() functions doens't work with const char* as first parameter.

Function:

---

```
char* GetWord(Words* head, int wordNumber)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < wordNumber; i++)
    head = head->pNext;
  char* result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(head->word) + 1));
  strcpy(result, head->word);
  return result;
}
```

---

I call it here:

---

```
int SaveInformationToFile(FILE** file, const char* filename, char* mode, Words* words, Data* data)
{
  if(OpenFile(file, filename, mode) == 0)
  {
    ErrorCreatingFile();
    return 0; /* error */
  }
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < NumberOfWords(words); i++)
  {
    char* tempWord = GetWord(words, i);
    FindWordInData(file, data, tempWord);
    free(tempWord);
  }
  CloseFile(file);
  return 1; /* no errors */
}
```

---

and here:

---

```
void FindWordInData(FILE** file, Data* head, char* word)
{
  fprintf(*file, "Word \'%s\' occurs in lines: \n", word);

  Data* temp = head;
  int numberOfOccurrences = 0;
  int j = 0;

  while(temp != NULL)
 {
   j = 0;
   Words* tempWord = temp->words;
   while(tempWord != NULL)
   {
     char* wordFromData = GetWord(temp->words, j);
     if(strcmp(word, wordFromData) == 0)
     {
       fprintf(*file, "%d ", temp->lineNumber);
       numberOfOccurrences++;
       break;
     }
     j++;
     tempWord = tempWord->pNext;
     free(wordFromData);
   }
   temp = temp->pNext;
 }
 if(numberOfOccurrences == 0)
  fprintf(*file,"-\n");
 else
  fprintf(*file,"\n");

}
```

---

How I know the leaks appears? It's part of Drmemory diagnosis:

---

```
Error #4: LEAK 3 direct bytes 0x014105b8-0x014105bb + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_malloc                      [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2577]
# 1 GetWord    
# 2 FindWordInData
# 3 SaveInformationToFile
# 4 main       

Error #5: LEAK 2 direct bytes 0x01411a10-0x01411a12 + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_malloc                     [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2577]
# 1 msvcrt.dll!_strdup   
# 2 .text      
# 3 __mingw_glob
# 4 _setargv   
# 5 .text      
# 6 ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart

Error #6: LEAK 2 direct bytes 0x014154e8-0x014154ea + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_malloc                     [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2577]
# 1 msvcrt.dll!_strdup   
# 2 .text      
# 3 __mingw_glob
# 4 _setargv   
# 5 .text      
# 6 ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:
    Error #   1:      5
    Error #   2:      5
    Error #   4:   2310
    Error #   5:      5

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      3 unique,    11 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      3 unique,  2316 total,  13322 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     11 unique,    15 total,   4537 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
```

---

Any ideas how to fix this function? :v

Comment: Your code is not complete. Errors can be in functions not shown.

Comment: Could be the second while loop in `FindWordInData()`. If the `strcmp()` function returns 0 the `break` section is hit and the `free(wordFromData)` is never executed.

Comment: Omg, it's shame but i didnt see it. Thanks <3

Comment: Btw.. to be sure. Drmemory info: "<memory was allocated before tool took control>" is problem from Windows and I cannot fix these leaks?

Comment: Glad I could help :). I've never used Drmemory, so I am probably not the right person to answer your question, sorry.

Comment: I mean, I asked wrong question. Could you look at the part of dr memory diagnosis (Error5 and Error6)? You think it's possible to fix? Or it is on Windows?

Comment: Just from looking at it I'd say it's something coming from the `msvcrt.dll` but I don't know exactly. It could be a follow up of something happening in the code you wrote. But from my point of view I'd say it's coming from inside. Like I said I've never worked with Drmemory and don't know how to exactly interpret the error message.

Comment: K, thanks. I appreciate